# Type check validation in Python - stuck in a loop

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am currently working on a database application using Python and SQLite3, alongside Tkinter to create the user interface. The application has a login function, where the user inputs their StaffID and password, and the program authenticates the user by searching a login table for the data input. I am trying to add a type check validation to the StaffID, where it can only be an integer, however, upon running the program, it seems to get stuck in a loop displaying the following output:
[image: Error message]

I have attached a snippet of the code below:

```
    def UserLogin(self): #Login function for staff members
        while True:
            try:
                staffid = int(self.Entry1.get())
                password = self.Entry2.get()
                with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db: #Connects to the database file
                    cursor = db.cursor()
                    find_user = ('SELECT * FROM Login WHERE StaffID = ? AND Password = ?')
                    cursor.execute(find_user, [(staffid),(password)])
                    results = cursor.fetchall()
                    if results:
                        for i in results:
                            self.Access()
                            MainMenu.create_Toplevel1(root)
                            self.quit()
                    else:
                        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "The staffID or password is incorrect, please try again.")                  
                        time.sleep(1)
                        return("exit")
                        
                        break
            except:
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Validation Error","Please enter the correct data type for StaffID")
                self.ClearEntries()
```

I am relatively new to Python, so any help is really appreciated, even if it is just to improve my code in general. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: split the `staffid = int(self.Entry1.get())` line into 2 lines `staffIDstr =self.Entry1.get()` and `staffID = int(staffIDstr)` , to see what you get from the Entry1.get() method. Then you can investigate, why it does not get parsed as int.

Comment: As a note, I would generally recommend not wrapping the entire function in a try/except, as the exception could be coming from anywhere in the method (including function calls you didn't expect to throw an exception) and you have no way of telling where from. It may be a good idea to just wrap the call to `int` in the try/except. That way if something else is raising an exception you'll see it, and can fix the mistake or put a more appropriate handler in. For the moment you could just change your except to only catch ValueError.

Comment: @Kemp changing my except worked perfectly. It will do for now, thanks so much.